# Index over % variables – how does the math work out?

Tags: r, ordinal-data, percentage

I'm coding in R. For my current project, I'm looking at data from OECD countries, and want to control for education level. The dataset has three relevant variables, that each describe % of population in a given country in a given year that has attained primary, secondary and tertiary education (e.g. UK, 1987, 30% completed primary, 50% completed secondary, 20% completed tertiary).

I want to construct an index that combines these three variables to express level of education in a country, such that it can be compared to others (some sort of mean educational level). I know how to code the index, but I'm very unsure about the math aspect of it. First I thought I cold just record education level to numeric values (1, 2 and 3), but this will make the math unbalanced (I think). Any feedback and ideas would be much appreciated.

Example of index from previous project:

```
df$indeks <- rowMeans(df[c('q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4', 'q5', 'q6')], na.rm=T)
```

These questions (q1-q6) were answered on a scale of 1-5 and all expressed the same sentiment.

Comment: How you code education level variable depends on what you use it for (graphs, models, etc). What will you use it for?

Comment: This is a theoretical question, and not really related to R. In theory you could just focus on one of the three variables und use that as an indicator of education level. They all are related anyways, since they will always sum to 100%. You could also model the index as an indicator of, how far an average person in that country travels through the educational system. Maybe by calculating the conditional probability of reaching a certain level of education.

Comment: @vanaoveneri In reality, these percentages don't always add up to 100 %, expecially for historical data from developing countries.

Comment: It might be sufficient to recode these percentages so that they are cumulative (e.g., 30/50/20 --> 100/70/20 (because completed teriary also means completed secondary and primary). Then you could just use the sum or mean of these.